# How to remove additional vertical line from dock created by Automator app

Tags: applications, automator, dock

[image]Can you help me by telling how to remove vertical line from dock created by Automator App. As you told that we can create it by following this process but i want to know how to remove it.

Using Automator to Create an App:

- Open Automator.
- Select "New Document" in the lower left.
- Choose a type for your document - Application.
- Find "Launch Application" from the list, and drag it into - the workspace on the right.
- Select the Finder app.

  - To do this, you have to go down to "New Variable." It will tell you to select the path. Click the dropdown, and go down to "Other." Do a search for "Finder.app" and select it.
  - Then click "Done."
- Click "Run" in the upper right hand corner, just to make sure it launches the Finder.
- Go to File > Export...

  - Name the file and choose a location for it. I picked my Applications folder.
  - Click Save.
- Repeat steps 7 & 8 for as many lines you want, changing the name each time. I kept the names numerical for ease of use. line1.app, line2.app, etc.

Comment: version- 10.15.6

Comment: Yes it is a developer beta

Comment: Please have a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

The **Automator** *workflow* isn't what caused the vertical lines, as there is nothing in the *workflow* capable of doing that. There is a new feature, since **macOS Mojave**, in **System Preferences** > **Dock** which added an additional vertical line, **[√] Show recent applications in Dock**. Uncheck it and the vertical line on the left will go away.